# RSpec and strings

Tags: ruby, rspec

In RSpec I have something like:

```
expect(a.my_method.map { |val| val.join("")}).to eq("#{SOME_MATRIX}")
```

where SOME_MATRIX is defined in another file as array, like:

```
SOME_MATRIX = ["OOOOO", "OOOOO", "OZOOO", "OZOOO", "OZOOO", "OZOOO"]
```

My test is not passing because of this error:

```
expected: "[\"OOOOO\", \"OOOOO\", \"OZOOO\", \"OZOOO\", \"OZOOO\", \"OZOOO\"]"
     got: ["OOOOO", "OOOOO", "OZOOO", "OZOOO", "OZOOO", "OZOOO"]
```

How can I write my string matrix to be the same as in expected value? Thanks.

Comment: try just: `....to eq(SOME_MATRIX)`

Comment: Awesome, it worked!